# Obtain title attribute from a tag using BeautifulSoup4

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Assume the following:

```
<a href="/wiki/Shanar" title="Shanar">I WANT THIS TEXT</a>
```

Now, I've successfully found respectively the table and individual rows using:

```
table = soup.find('table', class_='sortable')
table_buy_rows = table.find_all('tr')
for tr in table_buy_rows:
    td = tr.find('a')
    print(td.text)
```

By printing `td` I can see I've found the correct rows, but I'm really not sure how to take the text inner `a` tag.  I've attempted to use `print(td.text)`, but I'm getting errors doing this, so evidently I'm doing something wrong.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
import bs4

markup = """
<a href="/wiki/Shanar" title="Shanar">I WANT THIS TEXT</a>
"""
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(markup=markup)
a = soup.find('a')

print("inner: %s" % a.text)
print("title: %s" % a.attrs["title"])
```

Output:

```
inner: I WANT THIS TEXT
title: Shanar
```